# why is regular expression 'batRegex = re.compile(r'Bat(wo)+man') ' a bug？

Tags: python, regex, error-handling, compilation, python-re

I try to do this:

```
① batRegex = re.compile(r'Bat(wo)*+man')
```

and this:

```
mo3 = batRegex.search('My name is Batwowowowowowomanman.')
mo3.group()
```

And I expect this:

```
'Batwowowowowowoman'
```

But I got this when I type ①:

```
re.error: multiple repeat at position 8
```

I wonder what that means.
Because * means any times of repeat and + means at least one time repeat, that's exactly what happened in the mo3. What's wrong.

Thanks:)

My python version is Python 3.10.5.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex `Bat(wo)*+man`, the `*` already means to repeat the group `(wo)` zero or more times.  Therefore, the following `+` is out of place.  You probably intended to use `Bat(?:wo)+man`.  Here is an updated script:

```py
batRegex = re.compile(r'Bat(?:wo)+man') 
mo3 = batRegex.search('My name is Batwowowowowowomanman.')
print(mo3.group())  # Batwowowowowowoman
```